# Convert multiband image to image collection Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to convert my `ee.Image` which has 20 bands, to an `ee.ImageCollection`, where the information in each band is now stored in a single-band image. I've used the `.toBands()` function in the past: **I am essentially looking for the reverse**.

For example, in one `ee.Image`, My bands are named as follows:

```
"Arborimus_albipes"
"Chaetodipus_hispidus"
"Euderma_maculatum"
"Lasiurus_seminolus"
"Myotis_ciliolabrum"
"Neotoma_fuscipes"
"Nycticeius_humeralis" ....
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Map over the list of bands to produce images, then cast.

```
var bands = image.bandNames()
var list = bands.map(function(n) { return image.select([n]) })
var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list)
```

Comment: that worked. Perfect, thanks so much Noel!